# Livestream plagiarism of question titles from Math.SE onto Quora

Tags: discussion, copyright

I noticed this first [over at Chinese.SE](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/someone-seems-to-be-copy-pasting-question-titles-to-quora-without-attribution) and it turns out [it was reported 5 months ago on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342516/quora-users-bots-are-copying-a-significant-amount-of-stack-exchange-questions).    A Quora user Dex Jackson is copy/pasting large numbers of question titles from Stack Exchange onto Quora; this user's activity page is like a [*plagiarism livestream*](https://www.quora.com/profile/Dex-Jackson/activity).

I again reported this to Stack Exchange, but I'm not expecting much of a response.  I went to Quora, flagging multitudes of posts, filled in complaint forms, and providing answers linking to the original question, but this eventually got me [banned from Quora](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUHrS.png); they seem disinterested in fixing their problem.

This Quora user is plagiarizing material Stack Exchange wide.  Some recent math.SE posts are:

1. ***Math.SE*** (Jul 3 at 18:35): [What is the derivative of the following kernel function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3744125/what-is-the-derivative-of-the-following-kernel-function)
   ***Quora*** (2m ago): [What is the derivative of the following kernel function (calculus, matrices, derivatives, matrix calculus, matrix decomposition, math)?](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/What-is-the-derivative-of-the-following-kernel-function-calculus-matrices-derivatives-matrix-calculus-matrix-decomposition-math)
2. ***Math.SE*** (50 mins ago): [Proof of Hoffman & Kruskal's theorem on Unimodularity and Integrality.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3749170/proof-of-hoffman-kruskals-theorem-on-unimodularity-and-integrality)
   ***Quora*** (28m ago): [How do you provide a proof of Hoffman and Kruskal's theorem on Unimodularity and Integrality. (optimization, proof explanation, linear programming, integer programming, mixed integer, programming, math)?](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-do-you-provide-a-proof-of-Hoffman-and-Kruskals-theorem-on-Unimodularity-and-Integrality-optimization-proof-explanation-linear-programming-integer-programming-mixed-integer-programming-math)
3. ***Math.SE*** (1 hour ago): [basic linear algebra eigenvalue inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3749088/basic-linear-algebra-eigenvalue-inequality)
   ***Quora*** (1h ago): [How do you approach basic linear algebra eigenvalue inequality skepticism (linear algebra, eigenvalues, eigenvectors, math)?](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-do-you-approach-basic-linear-algebra-eigenvalue-inequality-skepticism-linear-algebra-eigenvalues-eigenvectors-math)
4. ***Math.SE*** (2 hours ago): [Reflecting over y=−x](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3749000/reflecting-over-y-x)
   ***Quora*** (1h ago): [How do you reflect over $y= x$ promptly (transformation, reflection, and math)?](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-do-you-reflect-over-y-x-promptly-transformation-reflection-and-math)
5. ***Math.SE*** (4 hours ago): [diffeomorphism and integration by transformation rate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3748915/diffeomorphism-and-integration-by-transformation-rate)
   ***Quora*** (2h ago): [How do you establish the diffeomorphism and integration by transformation rate (analysis, math)?](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-do-you-establish-the-diffeomorphism-and-integration-by-transformation-rate-analysis-math)
6. ***Math.SE*** (21 hours ago): [How do I solve a quadratic where x is in the denominator, x2−4x−3=0? [closed]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3748024/how-do-i-solve-a-quadratic-where-x-is-in-the-denominator-x2-frac4x-3-0)
   ***Quora*** (17h ago): [How do you solve a quadratic where $x$ is in the denominator, $x^2 \frac {4} {x} 3=0$ (algebra precalculus, math)?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-solve-a-quadratic-where-x-is-in-the-denominator-x-2-frac-4-x-3-0-algebra-precalculus-math)
   ***Quora (again)*** (3h ago): [How do you solve a quadratic where $x$ is in the denominator, $x^2 \frac {4} {x} 3=0$ (algebra, precalculus, math)?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-solve-a-quadratic-where-x-is-in-the-denominator-x-2-frac-4-x-3-0-algebra-precalculus-math-1)
7. ***Math.SE*** (17 hours ago): [Find the constant term in (x+1+1/x)7 [closed]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3748154/find-the-constant-term-in-x11-x7)
   ***Quora*** (3h ago): [How do you find the constant term in (x+1+1/x) ^7 (binomial theorem, math)?](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-do-you-find-the-constant-term-in-x-1-1-x-7-binomial-theorem-math)
8. ***Math.SE*** (17 hours ago): [Hadamard's formula and the Fibonacci sequence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3748152/hadamards-formula-and-the-fibonacci-sequence)
   ***Quora*** (15h ago): [How is Hadamard's formula applied to the Fibonacci sequence (sequences, series, convergence, divergence, math)?](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-is-Hadamards-formula-applied-to-the-Fibonacci-sequence-sequences-series-convergence-divergence-math)
9. ***Math.SE*** (18 hours ago): [Calculating end point coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3748114/calculating-end-point-coordinates)
   ***Quora*** (17h ago): [How do you calculate end point coordinates (geometry, trigonometry, quadratics, coordinate systems, math)?](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-do-you-calculate-end-point-coordinates-geometry-trigonometry-quadratics-coordinate-systems-math)
10. ***Math.SE*** (18 hours ago): [Puzzle about a spinning table with a coin on each corner.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3746554/puzzle-about-a-spinning-table-with-a-coin-on-each-corner)
    ***Quora*** (18h ago): [How do you handle a puzzle about a spinning table with a coin on each corner (combinatorics, combinations, puzzles binary, math)?](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-do-you-handle-a-puzzle-about-a-spinning-table-with-a-coin-on-each-corner-combinatorics-combinations-puzzles-binary-math)
11. ***Math.SE*** (19 hours ago): [Computing the homotopy type of the total space of a fiber bundle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3748083/computing-the-homotopy-type-of-the-total-space-of-a-fiber-bundle)
    ***Quora*** (18h ago): [How do you compute the homotopy type of the total space of a fiber bundle (algebraic topology, homology, cohomology, fundamental groups, math)?](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-do-you-compute-the-homotopy-type-of-the-total-space-of-a-fiber-bundle-algebraic-topology-homology-cohomology-fundamental-groups-math)
12. ***Math.SE*** (yesterday): [Solve the inequality |3x−5|−|2x+3|>0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3747907/solve-the-inequality-3x-5-2x3-0)
    ***Quora*** (18h ago): [How do you solve the inequality $|3x 5| |2x+3| >0$ (contextual inequality, absolute value, math)?](https://www.quora.com/When-defining-integer-numbers-via-formal-competition-how-does-the-continuity-of-multiplication-work-real-analysis-integer-number-theory-formal-completions-math)

I just want to alert you to this.

Comment: When I click on the Quora link I see only a title but no further text of the Math.SE post.. Is only the title of the post copied?

Comment: Yes, Quora questions only have titles.  Although people answer them at Quora rather than at Stack Exchange.

Comment: But most of this Quora questions do not make sense. Often the formulas they contain are mutilated. That does not make sense to me.

Comment: This seems mostly likely to be heavily scripted (but badly so) in some respect or another.

Comment: My theory is that he is trying to gain rep on either SO or Quora by duplicating the questions onto Quora, then taking whichever one gives him an answer first and pasting that answer into the other one. However, I checked on a handful of the ones above that have answers on both sites, and I haven't yet found any that are identical across the two sites. That doesn't mean my theory is wrong; it might just mean either he hasn't been successful yet or I haven't found the evidence.

Comment: Also, since the questions seem to come from many different Stacks, I thought perhaps he was taking them from the HNQ, but the questions above don't seem to be on the HNQ.

Comment: The things in parentheses are (1) a list of the tags from foo.SE, and (2) foo, the Stack.

Comment: Is there anything actually wrong with this? Assuming they are not using it to gain reputation on either site, it shouldn't cause any problems for 2 answer sites to have answers to the same questions. It may even be beneficial because Quora gives a different answer format to S.E.

Comment: Off the top of my head, aside from not giving attribution (violating copyright), some of the questions there get answers so the original question may end up with off-site answers (drawing people away from Stack Exchange), people are wasting their time answering questions by a disinterested user, and [Quora has a scheme where people get paid (actual money) for asking questions](https://growtraffic.com/blog/2018/07/how-money-earn-quora).

Comment: The last point is cause for concern. Also, are S.E. questions really copyrighted?

Comment: Yes, copyright is automatic on written work.  Most SE content is nowadays licensed under [Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International (CC BY-SA 4.0)](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) requiring attribution.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't have got banned from Quora for pointing this out.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22540/is-it-really-wrong-to-have-sites-copying-the-questions-and-answers-from-math-se (Not the exact same situation, but seemingly applicable.)

Comment: It might be more accurate to say [Quora has a scheme where they tell you they pay you real money for questions, but just before payout, there's a good chance they will ban you for unspecified rules violations](https://medium.com/@AntonioKowatsch/the-quora-partner-program-is-a-scam-9026c675cc7e).

Comment: @apkg This is right, but unfortunately I am not surprised. Quora is perfectly dreadful.

Comment: A question on [meta.se]: [Is Quora stealing questions / answers from Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318798) (It was recently bumped by a bounty.)

Comment: Compare [proof-of-infinitude-of-primes-by-eulers-product-formula-is-circular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3746532/proof-of-infinitude-of-primes-by-eulers-product-formula-is-circular) on MSE and [How-do-you-show-that-proof-of-infinitude-of-primes-by-Eulers-product-formula-is-circular](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-show-that-proof-of-infinitude-of-primes-by-Eulers-product-formula-is-circular) on Quora

Comment: See my answer over at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318798/is-quora-stealing-questions-answers-from-stack-exchange-sites.

Comment: @MartinSleziak It would be nicely ironic if *that* meta question made it into the "livestream" :)

Answer (score 20):

I actually got a reply from Quora (although I'm fairly sure it's just a template):

> Jim (Quora)
>
> Jul 8, 2020, 12:18 PM PDT
>
> Dear Rebecca‍,
>
> Thank you for your report. It appears from your claim that you do not
> own the copyright of the and/or are not authorized to act on behalf of
> the owner.
>
> We ask that you provide more specific evidence that you own the
> copyright to the content in question, such as a copyright registration
> or other information supporting your claim.
>
> Additionally, your complaint lacks certain information we need to
> understand and respond fully, in accordance with our policies and
> applicable laws, including the Digital Millennium Copyright Act
> (DMCA). Please note that a valid DMCA request must include the
> following information:
>
> - Identify the copyrighted work that you believe is being infringed
> - Identify the specific material that you believe is infringing
> - Identify specifically the location (e.g., the URL link) of each instance that the allegedly infringing work appears
>
> Once we have received a proper request, we will review your complaint
> in accordance with our policies and applicable law.
>
> We appreciate your understanding.
>
> Regards,
>
> Jim User Operations Quora
>
> ...
>
> Jul 6, 2020, 9:25 PM PDT
>
> Notice of alleged copyright infringement

Comment: Thanks for sharing. If Stack Exchange has an interest in this issue, they could help list all the questions that Dex Jackson copied. Note that Dex is not the only problematic Quora user, e.g. https://www.quora.com/profile/Steve-Tang-6/activity is also copying a large amount of Stack Exchange questions without any attribution.

Comment: Ah, I haven't looked closely at this account.  But yeah, there are copy/pasted titles there too: [Cooking.SE](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/109464) vs. [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-Hong-Kong-restaurants-use-dried-whelks-%E9%9F%BF%E8%9E%BA%E7%89%87-for-whelk-soup), and [Buddhism.SE](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/39629) vs. [Quora](https://www.quora.com/If-Buddhas-dont-feel-bliss-what-is-the-purpose-of-attaining-nirvana).

Comment: So those people are not at all interested in the ethical side of the matter - only the legal. Why am I not surprised.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think it's not possible to infer that from this reply alone. Just because one staff member at Quora wrote a reply which mentions only the legal side of things, does not mean that "these people" are not interested in the ethical side.

Comment: @user400188 The staff member in question is representing his employer, not expressing a personal opinion. I do not understand your objection.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yeah can't say I'm surprised either. Quora has always struck me as some "pretending to be intellectual" venture where the primary and perhaps only goal is to further their own brand rather than the pursuit of knowledge.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: believe it or not but Quora has succeeded in furthering their brand to some extent. Most of the time Quora comes up in the first page (even first link) when you type questions on Google. But people who look for real information would prefer stack exchange anytime over Quora.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: It's quora, not ethica.